# Override DataBind()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page.

In the C#:

```
public class myClass
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mydropdown1.DataSource = location_of_data;
        mydropdown1.DataBind();

        mydropdown2.DataSource = location_of_data;
        mydropdown2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Let's assume that the aspx file has 2 dropdowns.

I would like to overwride the DataBind function, keeping the current string the same, but I want to change the values of each item that I want to Bind.

I googled a solution of DataBind override which looks as follows:

```
public override void DataBind()
{
   //...some implementation here...
   base.DataBind()
}
```

but I am unsure if I should put thie override method in myClass. Also if I have two DropDowns and I want to treat their DataBinds differently, how should I approach this?

Comment: what about changing the incoming data instead? it seems better to my eyes. That said, take a look at the [ItemDataBound event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen to the dropdowns individual DataBinding event instead of handling it in the controls DataBind method. Then you can handle each of them individually as well.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    mydropdown1.DataBinding += binddropdown1;
    mydropdown1.DataBind();
}

private void binddropdown1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    mydropdown1.DataSource = dataSource;
}
```

then, when data changes that either of the dropdowns are concerned about, call the `dropdown.DataBind()` method and handle it there.